# LongListSelector not scrolling

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am having trouble getting my long list selector to work properly.  When the list is taller than the screen, the long list selector stays static and I am unable to scroll to see all of the items.

Any thoughts?

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationsHeader, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" x:Name="applicationsPivotItem">
    <Grid x:Name="applications" Grid.Row="1">
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix the Height of the Grid

```
<Grid x:Name="applications" Grid.Row="1" Height="400">
...long list code...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Doesn't this generally go against the guidelines for creating a responsive design?  Setting an explicit height like that can cause UI strangeness when running the app on devices with different resolutions.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue where my panoramaItem was defines as below:

```
            <phone:PanoramaItem>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="SpeciesList" Grid.Row="0">
                        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,-6,0,12">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PrimaryName}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

By changing the RowDefinition to use * instead of Auto, my scrolling issues was resolved! As shown below.

```
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the LongListSelector not scrolling.  In the end it was OpacityMask="White" that was set in LongListSelector that was causing the issue [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408962/strange-behaviour-with-longlistselector-and-opacity-on-windows-phone-8)

Also as per Mattias I didn't have to set a specific Height, as long as the grid RowDefinition was set to *.